# Api-platform, entity just for calcul, not linked with database -> invalid identifier configuration

Tags: api-platform.com

I try to add an url to make some calculs in api platform. So i make an entity like this

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/calcul",
 *              "controller"=CalculController::class
 *          }
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"output"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"input"}}
 * )
 */
class Calcul
{
    /**
     * @var array
     * @Groups({"input"})
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @Groups({"output"})
     */
    private $result;
```

And I get this error :

`"Not found, because of an invalid identifier configuration"`

I added that (although I do not use it)

```php
/**
     * @var int
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $id;
```

But I get the same error message.

Someone have an idea please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Post operations should be collection operations:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/calcul",
 *              "controller"=CalculController::class
 *          }
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"output"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"input"}}
 * )
 */
class Calcul
//..
```

But then you get the following error
"No identifiers defined for resource of type "App\Entity\Calcul"",

After adding the id property you described, a ::getId method and setting some value to $id, it works.

But having a fake id is not very tidy. You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744246/operation-without-entity)